# Unable to browse SharePoint 2013 Central Administration or SharePoint sites. get the event error 3760

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2008-r2, sharepointadmin

Please help me regarding this issues.
I have no idea about sharepoint admin issues.

when i'm try to start SharePoint 2013 Central Administration or share-point site so it's not start.
when i checked event logs.
I got error **3760**.

> SQL Database 'SharePoint_Config' on SQL Server instance 'xxx' not
>   found. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
>   Cannot open database "SharePoint_Config" requested by the login. The
>   login failed.Login failed for user 'xxx\Administrator'.

Please check below screenshot.

Please suggest me 
and share me some link related this issues.
[image]

Comment: go to active directory and unlock administrator

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for your reply. our user not lock already  checked.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user password expired?

For such case, you need update it.

Reference [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36418.sharepoint-2013-how-to-change-all-service-account-passwords.aspx) and [here](https://threewill.com/reset-a-sharepoint-2013-service-account-password/).

Comment: Thanks Lee for your answer , password not expired.

Comment: Try to logon DB server and check whether the user could access the DB, so it would help to identify the issue.

Comment: Ohh Thanks Lee, Our Administrator user not available in SharePoint Config DB. In SQL In AD user available. Can you suggest me what I do now? How can add User in Db.Please send me a link if possible. Thank you so much .